# Xamarin.iOS Crashs Without Any Exception

Tags: xamarin.ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm using xamarin.iso indie version and xamarin studio to develop a small application.
At begining, everything gos well, but after I add the search function which involves the UISearchDisplayController and UISearchDisplayDelegate, then I always get the application crash.
everytime, if I search for the firs time, then it works, and the controller will be navigated back to the main controller, but when I go into the search controller again, the application will crash when I click on the button which will trigger the naviagation to search controller or when I input the search text on the search bar.
The debugger doesn't pop up any exception or meesage, just disconected from the iPad. so I don't what's really wrong with my code.

I spend about one week on this code and changes any code that possible has the error, and add all try/catch to all the functions reladted, but none of them has a break when the application crash.

How can I do to get whats's really happened?

Thanks

I added the crash report:
        Incident Identifier: 4E7BF3F6-6C51-4F31-9FCA-BFBBFF4BA784
        CrashReporter Key:   d9f9b03f7f2af1d1b10851aec8a44d4127285508
        Hardware Model:      iPad3,4
        Process:         MODClientiOSModPad [300]
        Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/2CBA3949-EF3E-4F85-98AC-439FEEC7CF07/MODClientiOSModPad.app/MODClientiOSModPad
        Identifier:      MODClientiOSModPad
        Version:         ??? (???)
        Code Type:       ARM (Native)
        Parent Process:  launchd [1]

```
    Date/Time:       2013-06-03 23:09:16.965 +0800
    OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
    Report Version:  104

    Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
    Crashed Thread:  0

    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39aac350 __pthread_kill + 8
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39a22fb2 pthread_kill + 54
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39a5f366 abort + 90
    3   MODClientiOSModPad              0x001b3796 0x1000 + 1779606
    4   MODClientiOSModPad              0x001ba5b4 0x1000 + 1807796
    5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39a2cd38 _sigtramp + 40
    6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39a22fb2 pthread_kill + 54
    7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39a5f366 abort + 90
    8   MODClientiOSModPad              0x00196866 0x1000 + 1661030
    9   MODClientiOSModPad              0x001d98e2 0x1000 + 1935586
    10  MODClientiOSModPad              0x001e0cfe 0x1000 + 1965310
    11  MODClientiOSModPad              0x001e0e1a 0x1000 + 1965594
    12  MODClientiOSModPad              0x00205064 0x1000 + 2113636
    13  MODClientiOSModPad              0x00200b64 0x1000 + 2095972
    14  MODClientiOSModPad              0x00002024 0x1000 + 4132

    Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
    Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39a9c5d0 kevent64 + 24
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x399d7d22 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 806
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x399d3374 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 32

    Thread 2:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39aacd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x399faad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x399fa7f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
    3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x399fa680 start_wqthread + 4

    Thread 3:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39aac494 __recvfrom + 20
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39a05192 recv + 18
    2   MODClientiOSModPad              0x00201f50 0x1000 + 2101072
    3   MODClientiOSModPad              0x002035a4 0x1000 + 2106788
    4   MODClientiOSModPad              0x00203260 0x1000 + 2105952
    5   MODClientiOSModPad              0x00201d3c 0x1000 + 2100540
    6   MODClientiOSModPad              0x00200d9c 0x1000 + 2096540
    7   Foundation                      0x3204622c __NSThread__main__ + 968
    8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39a050de _pthread_start + 306
    9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39a04fa4 thread_start + 4

    Thread 4:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39aacd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x399faad6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x399fa7f2 _pthread_wqthread + 362
    3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x399fa680 start_wqthread + 4

    Thread 5:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39aac494 __recvfrom + 20
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39a05192 recv + 18
    2   MODClientiOSModPad              0x00201f50 0x1000 + 2101072
    3   MODClientiOSModPad              0x00202054 0x1000 + 2101332
    4   MODClientiOSModPad              0x0017e166 0x1000 + 1560934
    5   MODClientiOSModPad              0x0016d136 0x1000 + 1491254
    6   MODClientiOSModPad              0x0018f148 0x1000 + 1630536
    7   MODClientiOSModPad              0x001b0628 0x1000 + 1766952
    8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39a050de _pthread_start + 306
    9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39a04fa4 thread_start + 4

    Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
        r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x3b599524
        r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3b599b78      r6: 0x0021b34b      r7: 0x2fdff374
        r8: 0x0021af65    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x0021b398     r11: 0x011e5e30
        ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdff368      lr: 0x39a22fb7      pc: 0x39aac350
      cpsr: 0x00000010

    Binary Images:
        0x1000 -   0x295fff +MODClientiOSModPad armv7  <b2d6686664c73a99a57ed66e4118b516> /var/mobile/Applications/2CBA3949-EF3E-4F85-98AC-439FEEC7CF07/MODClientiOSModPad.app/MODClientiOSModPad
    0x2fe7a000 - 0x2fe9afff  dyld armv7s  <67efe80b9d863d6bb30fe51e6e17b070> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x3092a000 - 0x3092afff  Accelerate armv7s  <f4e8c4c464953429ab6bd3160aadd176> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
    0x3092b000 - 0x30a68fff  vImage armv7s  <49d3cf19d0a23f4d836fc313e5fd6bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
    0x30a69000 - 0x30b55fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7s  <584e045442be39fc847ffe1a5e4c99b2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
    0x30b56000 - 0x30e0cfff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7s  <30a3e7dd8c603a9d81b5e42704ba5971> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x30e0d000 - 0x30e65fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7s  <936354553eb93d2dafa76ffcad65f9b7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
    0x30e66000 - 0x30e78fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7s  <5fae8715a0403315bb1991b79677f916> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
    0x30e79000 - 0x30e79fff  vecLib armv7s  <30275ee8819331229ba21256d7b94596> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
    0x31383000 - 0x31448fff  CFNetwork armv7s  <ef41814d8641319c96cdeb1264d2d150> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
    0x31449000 - 0x3149ffff  CoreAudio armv7s  <19aa715b19a93a5c8563dbc706e899be> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
    0x3166c000 - 0x3179efff  CoreFoundation armv7s  <bd8e6c9f94b43e3d9af96a0f03ff3011> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
    0x3179f000 - 0x318d8fff  CoreGraphics armv7s  <ef057fe1c715314cabf133ec26fa718c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
    0x31b15000 - 0x31bcafff  CoreImage armv7s  <7d7cd7998a113ed9b483e7dc9f388b05> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
    0x31c58000 - 0x31cbdfff  CoreMedia armv7s  <526b25ed6f4e31b790553bd80d46fec7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
    0x31d47000 - 0x31d9dfff  CoreTelephony armv7s  <930c89780b123ecea46cff85c4989982> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
    0x31d9e000 - 0x31e00fff  CoreText armv7s  <a01bc990cb483e828f7c3e08cd446daf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
    0x31e01000 - 0x31e10fff  CoreVideo armv7s  <851591a704dc344aa2fc397094b4c622> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
    0x31f95000 - 0x32158fff  Foundation armv7s  <0f73c35ada563c0bb2ce402d282faefd> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
    0x32313000 - 0x3235cfff  IOKit armv7s  <4e5e55f27bbb35bab7af348997bfac17> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x3235d000 - 0x32535fff  ImageIO armv7s  <e04300f6e6b232ce8a02139d8f18dfdc> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
    0x32a4c000 - 0x32aa5fff  MobileCoreServices armv7s  <b0d1162a8ab03529bb90e416895b568a> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
    0x32b95000 - 0x32b9cfff  OpenGLES armv7s  <c9c8f7cbfbe5397382286b878bdf143c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
    0x32b9e000 - 0x32b9efff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7s  <b7d1ddfeb0db36d6af7293fa625b12be> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
    0x32ba2000 - 0x32ba4fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7s  <8bcac434962435a895fa0b0a3a33b7a1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
    0x32ba5000 - 0x32ba9fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7s  <272a9de67f6632c3aebbe2407cfe716b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
    0x32baa000 - 0x32be9fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7s  <3a444257935236fab123e46e617c7a8d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
    0x332e9000 - 0x333fdfff  QuartzCore armv7s  <b28fd354be3c38a2965e6368fa35e0c7> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
    0x3344b000 - 0x33479fff  Security armv7s  <e1fcc8913eba360c868f51558a01cf24> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
    0x334f8000 - 0x33537fff  SystemConfiguration armv7s  <0fb8d4a2fa8f30ce837e068a046e466b> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
    0x3353a000 - 0x33a8dfff  UIKit armv7s  <62bee9294ca13738bd7ff14365dc8561> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
    0x33a8e000 - 0x33acdfff  VideoToolbox armv7s  <57487f6e3c38304ab0aa14dd16043f5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
    0x33d97000 - 0x33d9afff  AggregateDictionary armv7s  <52b69c81243d3e7ea280defa4802aa0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
    0x341c6000 - 0x34201fff  AppSupport armv7s  <7d6122cb42363dc981247c926e637a34> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
    0x34274000 - 0x3427dfff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7s  <ec78d21573a23c34b6cec05ba56928f1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
    0x342ad000 - 0x342c4fff  BackBoardServices armv7s  <7fd28bde9e3b3a62a5758e9e859db9fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
    0x342ce000 - 0x342f2fff  Bom armv7s  <f35bf1c1b24a3742847383801ac37505> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
    0x34528000 - 0x3452dfff  CommonUtilities armv7s  <eb0b7e85b57e32f38dc498c0ee97aa7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
    0x347f3000 - 0x347f4fff  CoreSurface armv7s  <55826212d8b4352b87d80f93bc9b25c6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
    0x34861000 - 0x34866fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7s  <3b190badb14f3771b353fcd829719c80> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
    0x34a8d000 - 0x34aa6fff  DictionaryServices armv7s  <27298e235f2c35938e1033517b1196a7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
    0x34b19000 - 0x34f2cfff  FaceCoreLight armv7s  <432cbaeb84743441b9286532bc36c96d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
    0x35124000 - 0x35130fff  GenerationalStorage armv7s  <4e1afa8de682332ba6a042a6000c636e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
    0x3522b000 - 0x35236fff  GraphicsServices armv7s  <44b33c403523309c9e930818c7fced34> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
    0x35522000 - 0x3556efff  IMFoundation armv7s  <55151f53b10934c3a5faac54e354f3f1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
    0x35575000 - 0x35576fff  IOAccelerator armv7s  <832913083f7f347fba1340263ff13b52> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
    0x35577000 - 0x3557cfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7s  <828a36a2325738bb8f2d4b97730d253a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
    0x3557d000 - 0x35581fff  IOSurface armv7s  <9925fbc4a08d3a17b72ac807cbbba8ba> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
    0x355cb000 - 0x35772fff  JavaScriptCore armv7s  <f7be721eee903a93a7de361e5627445e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
    0x35a6d000 - 0x35a9afff  MobileAsset armv7s  <e3217ead58d5390395de360b3ca3a10a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
    0x35adf000 - 0x35ae2fff  MobileInstallation armv7s  <7cbe167946123bbea56ae58208e09762> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
    0x35ae3000 - 0x35ae9fff  MobileKeyBag armv7s  <5c7d50e11eb537ae89ea12cb7ddd3935> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
    0x35b46000 - 0x35b49fff  MobileSystemServices armv7s  <5796fff2895f38e4b0f844269d4fbae5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
    0x36421000 - 0x36445fff  OpenCL armv7s  <9fb5ca4c594c3ae8baf7e0b0c299733b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
    0x36a5a000 - 0x36a82fff  PrintKit armv7s  <7109f645a9ca3a4997b4172aed228723> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
    0x36a83000 - 0x36af7fff  ProofReader armv7s  <e391e8d141c5352d978e5fde23afaaad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
    0x36c3c000 - 0x36c4dfff  SpringBoardServices armv7s  <bb92c069669b36959d3e82d4144f4264> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
    0x36dd8000 - 0x36ddafff  TCC armv7s  <95c2aa492cc03862bd7bbfae6fa62b1b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
    0x36df9000 - 0x36e06fff  TelephonyUtilities armv7s  <aa759d908b903f978ab6803b7947e524> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TelephonyUtilities
    0x3728b000 - 0x3732bfff  UIFoundation armv7s  <e3a40cee28653c4485a4918016ff2b8e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
    0x3762f000 - 0x3764efff  WebBookmarks armv7s  <ab55332c13da33fd825ea6204338fe19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
    0x3764f000 - 0x37f7ffff  WebCore armv7s  <b87e1ce4e58231108043c9ae79bb01d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
    0x37f80000 - 0x3805cfff  WebKit armv7s  <6bd57205f7a43f6eb49f3037b57cc5f6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
    0x38107000 - 0x3810efff  XPCObjects armv7s  <e6846a96a21d382f9fffd6a4536c0aa7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
    0x38e30000 - 0x38e36fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7s  <9111bc894a4f3ef683f5ef4d699a861b> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
    0x38e37000 - 0x38e4dfff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7s  <770ebb2f7d9a35749e6da5d1980c244f> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
    0x38e65000 - 0x38e71fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7s  <7cf3ae0983a830d1a5dc91edb216b3f8> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
    0x38e83000 - 0x38e83fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7s  <12daef214fd234158028c97c22dc5cca> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x38fa1000 - 0x38fadfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7s  <0f4a8d65b05a364abca1a97e2ae72cb5> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
    0x38fae000 - 0x38fb7fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7s  <f54b70863d9c3751bb59253b1cb4c706> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
    0x38fb8000 - 0x39003fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7s  <3beff5a5233b3f51ab2fc748b68e9519> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x39004000 - 0x39017fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7s  <f47a5c7bc24c3e4fa73f11b61af635da> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x39048000 - 0x39135fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7s  <81d6972465103fa3b85b4125f0ad33f1> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
    0x39136000 - 0x3927ffff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7s  <642482cfc34a3a3b97bd731258dcdc6a> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x39287000 - 0x39287fff  liblangid.dylib armv7s  <ffb53baa33ba3642a55737311f17a672> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
    0x3928a000 - 0x39291fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7s  <d484b93ed83c3b0bb5c6721134662453> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
    0x395b0000 - 0x396aefff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7s  <1d499765d38c3c8fa92b363f529a02dd> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x39772000 - 0x39787fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7s  <3f7be9d397d63b8e931d21bd5f49b0eb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
    0x397ac000 - 0x39832fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7s  <758898189dca32a5a19e5200b8952110> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
    0x39833000 - 0x3987ffff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7s  <249e8ca1717b370287bb556bbd96e303> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
    0x39880000 - 0x398a6fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7s  <96b463f0ffa0344699fce4d48aa623bc> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
    0x398aa000 - 0x39957fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7s  <e87724e212573773a60bc56815cec706> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
    0x39958000 - 0x39978fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7s  <c52fbe01ce7b35c799630e97e8f1318b> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
    0x39979000 - 0x39985fff  libz.1.dylib armv7s  <b64a5c1989ba3ba4aafae83d841f9496> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x39986000 - 0x39989fff  libcache.dylib armv7s  <911ce99a94623ef1ae1ea786055fd558> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x3998a000 - 0x39990fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7s  <33140a5fa3fb3e5e8c6bb19bc0e21c5c> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x39991000 - 0x39993fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7s  <cd17f0ee3dbc38f99910d12a6056bf5a> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x39994000 - 0x39999fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7s  <5e733170766430eeaa4e7784e3c7555c> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x3999a000 - 0x399d0fff  libcorecrypto.dylib armv7s  <a15c807dcb003ad69810546a578774d9> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x399d1000 - 0x399e1fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7s  <247a388103633e17b24be038eac612c0> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x399e2000 - 0x399e3fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7s  <f873dd712561350096b9452bf1fc4078> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
    0x399e4000 - 0x399e5fff  libdyld.dylib armv7s  <d8d1e76c619b3a7cacfc4dc30a50d9bc> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x399e6000 - 0x399e6fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7s  <b0a1a911d4853feba44133e9ce499bc9> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x399e7000 - 0x399ecfff  liblaunch.dylib armv7s  <69dd64aba1413e75967cd4ad0afa2c15> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x399ed000 - 0x399f0fff  libmacho.dylib armv7s  <5905b311c6fb376388e56a991bb3193d> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x399f1000 - 0x399f2fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7s  <b40e964d7c563296b38625bc7082d6a8> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x399f3000 - 0x399f3fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7s  <77a9976b82b73796a0bbc9783929a1e7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x399f4000 - 0x39a7afff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7s  <11bcf1060ec63c8b909a452e6f79be08> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x39a7b000 - 0x39a81fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7s  <94fab309ed9b35cdbc075cdda221bc70> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x39a82000 - 0x39a9afff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7s  <195d8eeb7c3f31bd916c0b5611abc0e7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x39a9b000 - 0x39ab1fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7s  <a6afa72d4ec335d79b63aa47114cc24a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x39ab2000 - 0x39acefff  libsystem_m.dylib armv7s  <faafc8292d4935c4a78233e1d0879e13> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x39acf000 - 0x39addfff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7s  <137f48e279a83d7496659c8e3d3729d4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x39ade000 - 0x39ae5fff  libsystem_notify.dylib armv7s  <df14146497cb3fa0a002eedbed49da65> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x39ae6000 - 0x39ae7fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7s  <85e91e99abc03db88eddc665424090b4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x39ae8000 - 0x39ae8fff  libunwind.dylib armv7s  <3b7ec561dbec3a199f09ea08a64e76ee> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x39ae9000 - 0x39afefff  libxpc.dylib armv7s  <0562a59bdf8d3f7783e93f35d7e724a8> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
```

Comment: can you post a code sample from the section that is executing when it crashes?

Comment: actually, no code throw exception, the crash button is just a Segue which will navigate to the search controller, I set the break point, and the when the Segue is triggerd, the prepareSegue success fully executed, and the search controller's code haven't been executed, the application crash and the debugger exit without any error

Comment: Try getting the device log and crash reports as explained here: http://rolfkvinge.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/native-crashes-in-monotouch.html

Comment: I attached the crash reports. Thanks